# NHibernate Stored procedure with XML parameter

Tags: xml, nhibernate

I think I'm going crazy on this one : it's a fairly simple scenario and should be documented, but... no!

Here is my stored procedure declaration:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spImport]
(
    @xmlDocument AS XML
)
AS
---
GO
```

Here is my mapping:

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   assembly="XXX"
                   namespace="XXX.Entities">
    <sql-query name="spImport">
        <![CDATA[EXEC [dbo].[spImport] @xmlDocument = :xmlDocument]]>
    </sql-query>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

And Here is the calling method:

```
session.GetNamedQuery("spImport").SetParameter("xmlDocument", document, NHibernateUtil.XmlDoc).ExecuteUpdate();
```

Now, I'm getting the follinging error:

> While preparing EXEC [dbo].[spImport] @xmlDocument
>   = @p0 an error occurred InnerException: SqlCommand.Prepare method requires all variable length parameters to have an explicitly set
>   non-zero Size.

Thanks for your help,
Stefan

Answer (score 1):

Never took time to really solve the XmlType length problem . Would be interested in the "clean" answer. Anyway, here is my workaround :

I assume you are using a NHibernateUtil.XmlDoc: IUserType.

As SqlTypes implementation, I have :

```
    public SqlType[] SqlTypes
    {
        get 
        {
            return new SqlType[] { new SqlXmlType() };
        }
    }
```

where SqlXmlType is :

```
  public class SqlXmlType : SqlType
    {
        public SqlXmlType() : base(System.Data.DbType.Xml,5000000)
        {
        }

    }
```

Allowing me to handle up to 5 Mo XmlDocs

Hope this will help

Comment: Hi, this is great, thanks. However, like you, I would really appreciate to have a clean solution !